# Create a table from a list with lag values

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list as

list1 = {1,2,3,4,5}

How could I create a table such that the first entry is the lagged entry of this list, i.e:

table1 = {{0,1},{1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5}}

Thank you.

Comment: `Partition[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the third and fourth arguments of `Partition`:

```
Partition[list1, 2, 1, {-1, -1}, 0]
```

> {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}

Alternatively,

```
Transpose[{Most @ #, Rest @ #}] & @ Prepend[list1, 0]
```

> {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}